# Why is tabsetPanel displaying over my datatable? R Shiny

Tags: r, user-interface, shiny, dashboard

I've been at this for a couple of days now with little luck. 
Whenever I comment out the tabsetPanels from my code, the datatable (DT) is displaying itself. However, when the tabsetPanels are left in, the datatable is nowhere to be found. 
Why is this and how can I fix this?

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(data.table)

# Define UI ----
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Alpha"),
  mainPanel(
    fluidRow(
      tabsetPanel(id = 'tpanel',
                  type = "tabs",
                  tabPanel("Alpha", plotOutput("plot")),
                  tabPanel("Beta", plotOutput("plot")),
                  tabPanel("Delta",  plotOutput("plot")),
                  tabPanel("Omega", plotOutput("plot")))
      ),
    br(),
    br(),
    fluidRow(
      splitLayout(
        dateInput("sdate", "Start Date"),
        dateInput("edate", "End Date"),
        textInput("gmin", "Minimum"),
        textInput("gmax", "Maximum")
      )
    ),
    br(),
    DT::dataTableOutput('tbl')
  )
)

# Define server logic ----
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$tbl <- renderDT({datatable(port, editable = 'cell', caption = 'test')})
}

# Run the app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

This is what the following code outputs, notice the missing datatable:
[image]

When I remove/comment out the tabsetPanel the datatable displays normally. 
I should also add that the variable port is loaded in memory from a csv, and I have it there for ease. I loaded it manually prior to starting this script and I am only doing it manually as I learn to get the hang of shiny. Lastly, when I run the following script, it runs without issue:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(data.table)

# Define UI ----
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Alpha"),
  DT::dataTableOutput('tbl')
  )
)

# Define server logic ----
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$tbl <- renderDT({datatable(port, editable = 'cell', caption = 'test')})
}

# Run the app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

When I add the tabsetPanels to the code above, the datatable does not display. Why is this and how can I fix it?

Comment: Is there a reason the datatable needs to be outside the tabset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shiny is confused by the fact that there are several times the same ID for an output at `plotOutput("plot")`, so isn't able to render any output.

Here's the fix:

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(data.table)

# Define UI ----
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Alpha"),
  mainPanel(
    fluidRow(
      tabsetPanel(id = 'tpanel',
                  type = "tabs",
                  tabPanel("Alpha", plotOutput("plot1")),
                  tabPanel("Beta", plotOutput("plot2")),
                  tabPanel("Delta",  plotOutput("plot3")),
                  tabPanel("Omega", plotOutput("plot4")))
    ),
    br(),
    br(),
    fluidRow(
      splitLayout(
        dateInput("sdate", "Start Date"),
        dateInput("edate", "End Date"),
        textInput("gmin", "Minimum"),
        textInput("gmax", "Maximum")
      )
    ),
    br(),
    DT::dataTableOutput('tbl')
  )
)

# Define server logic ----
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$tbl <- renderDT({datatable(iris, editable = 'cell', caption = 'test')})
}

# Run the app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```